# What's up with innerHTML and <embed>?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, innerhtml

I'm trying to fix a bug in a rich text editor I'm using, which causes `<embed>` tags to be inserted without their closing tag (which screws the output up completely). I've isolated the problem to this operation:

```
// body is a <body> tag
body.innerHTML = '<embed src="http://example.com/whatever"></embed>';
```

No fancy code, just Firefox's `innerHTML` assignment. You should be able to duplicate the error in Firebug like so:

```
>>> document.body.innerHTML = "<embed></embed>"
"<embed></embed>"
>>> document.body.innerHTML
"<embed>"
```

Is there a workaround for this? I need the  tag, but I can't justify rebuilding/replacing the entire rich text editor because of one crappy edge case.

I can't convert this to something like `document.createElement('embed')`, because real-world input to this editor can easily include a few paragraphs of text wrapped around the `<embed>`; innerHTML is, on paper, perfect for this use case, I just can't get it to work with an `<embed>`.

Comment: Would it work for you if you create <object><embed></object> ? Will it still foobar your content?

Comment: mfn -- wrapping the <embed> in an <object> made it not show at all in Google Chrome, but (oddly enough) wrapping it in a <p> was enough to fix the display problems in RSS readers. If you post that as an answer, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be an answer to your problem, but *<embed>* was not part of any standardized version of HTML until HTML5, according to [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html).

Comment: Very true, so +1. But unfortunately, people use it, and it's the source of a nasty bug that, in the right circumstances, cuts off all content after the unclosed <embed>. ;)

Comment: Not totally true anymore; `<embed>` has been added to the HTML5 spec. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-embed-element

Answer (score 1):

Although <embed> is not a part of a standard html, it has been widely implemented and is, therefore, a de-facto standard.

That said, I'm running Firefox 3 (MineField v3.0.0.5) and am getting slightly unexpected, but altogether correct functionality. I was expecting the *exact* HTML to be put into the element I selected, but instead I got *clean* html.

Since <embed is an empty tag (that is, it cannot have contents, only attributes), Firefox turns this

```
<embed attribute="value"></embed>
```

into

```
<embed  attribute="value"/>
```

, which is  a prefectly valid closed tag. It does the same on other empty tags, such as <input /> and <image>

At the [this page](http://yaauie.com/stackoverflow/437086/) you can see this in action. The scriptless version of the page has an embedded video (youtube) inside of a bright pink div. The script steals its contents and places it into the body as innerHTML.

Comment: I was under the impression that a de facto standard was a standard that was nearly universal.  However, given that object (the standard version) is just as widely supported and used quite a bit, I wouldn't consider embed is a de facto standard.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the problems document.write had/has with <script /> tags.

Lies.  Don't answer SO questions right before bed.

<s>I tried the following in Firebug</s>

```
//break up initial embed into single chunks
document.body.innerHTML = "<e"+"mbe"+"d></embed>"
```

and got the expected  to show up when I checked the value of innerHTML.  The idea here is to break up the initial  string into multiple concatenated strings. Stupid, but a possible work-around.

Comment: The problem you are referring to is that script-tags can't contain any tags and that the parser sees the start of the end tag: "</". If you had used the format "<element><\/element>" in your document.write it had worked.

Comment: As I understand it, that'd just evaluate to "<embed></embed>" before assignment, the same thing that fails.I've also tried stuff like innerHTML += "</embed>".

Trying to break the assignment into multiple lines (like `innerHTML += "</embe"`) just throws errors.

Comment: Weird, sorry about that.  I thought I'd run though a bunch of tests, but it's not working now.  I'm fired.

Comment: You gave me another idea to test, though. Those are always good.

We could always put in a feature request for a "Mail Goggles" style SO feature: Solve some addition/programming puzzles in under 60 seconds to post! ;)